# Regex to match a word with special characters that starts with hash and ends with space

Tags: regex, special-characters

Given the text:

```
This is a #tag and this is another #love@irc.oftc.net and more text.
```

I would like to match the words starting with a hash and ends with a whitespace character ( i don't want to specify a specific pattern for `#love@irc.oftc.net` ).

I can't use `lookarounds` and would prefer not to use `\b`.

I have tried `#.*\b`, `#.*\s`, which will match more than i asked for. I guess the `*` will also match whitespace so the last check is ignored.

I use https://regexr.com/ for testing.

Comment: Do you want `#\S+`? Well, probably `\B#\S+` will be better.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the `#\S+` works and is the most compact one, please add an answer for it and i will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use

```
#\S+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NUlRyq/1).

**Details**

- `#` - a `#` symbol
- `\S+` - 1 or more characters other than whitespace (it can also be written as `[^\s]*`, but `\S` is just shorter).

As a possible enhancement, you can still consider using word and non-word boundaries. E.g., when you want to avoid matching `abc#tagliketext` or when you need to avoid matching punctuation at the end of the hashtag, you may consider using

```
\B#\S+\b
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NUlRyq/2%5C). The `\B` non-word boundary will fail the match if there is a word char before `#`, and `\b` will stop matching before the rightmost non-word char.

Answer (score 3):

You can match every character except space in the middle.

Try this:

```
#[^\s]+\s
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5w1xkK/2)